# How to extend a WIP git repository

Tags: git

For a hobby I'm working on a little personal project, the project is based on an active open source project which is updated on a daily basis.

Since I'm in close contact with the developer of the base-project, I have to be able to update the repository without destroying my own changes.

So I came up with the following and I was wondering if there is some sort of usual flow on how to achieve this goal.

Right now I made a fork, and worked on the project in the fork repository. I encountered a bug in the base project which the developer has fixed. After the fix, I did a merge which resulted in a catastrophe for my project and its config files.

Nothing gone, but this is not easy to work with.

So I was wondering if there is some sort of generally accepted method on how to achieve the situation in which I can:

- still pull the base project
- be able to build & run without too much delay (I can override the baseproject files with my files in a separate directory, but it takes time with all my custom icons and media to copy each time I run.)

Comment: If there is a conflict when merging, you resolve it by hand. There is no catastrophe. Sounds like you should describe your catastrophe in more detail in order for us to provide anything more than our sympathies.

Comment: I know and I did. But the base project changes so often that I don't want to fix merge conflicts each time there is an update. Plus that config files I need to edit, are merged too. So I'd like to have a separate base project repo which files I do not touch. And work on my own project in a separate folder which overrides something. If there is no generally accepted answer I will extend the server to first check in my_project folder, if the file does not exist it takes the file of the base project.

Comment: Have you tried [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)? It could be more appropriate since it can replay all your changes on the current HEAD of the upstream project.

Comment: Not yet, will take a look at it. But i'd rather not touch their repo at all. It's much cleaner to discuss changes etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a solution to the problem. First of all, you have to have a better understanding of the workings of remote branches (and branching). Then use fetch!

That was the short answer. Long answer follows.

Your local repo has a tracking branch. Probably, it's the branch you are working on and its name is `master` maybe. And the branch it is tracking is called upstream branch (probably it's the master branch you are pulling and its name is `origin/master` maybe). You should know that these are two different branches. To see this, try running `git branch -avv`, this lists your branches and the relation between the local and remote branches if exist. Also it tells how many commits you have that you haven't been merged into the origin/master and vice versa.

If you want to keep your repo updated without merging with your current local branch, use fetch: `git fetch origin`. This updates your local repo without merging with you working directory. You can do the merge later on.

**NOTE** you shouldn't merge or pull unless you have a clean working directory. If you don't, you might want to either create a commit, stash your changes or create a commit in another temporary branch.

To have more clear image, maybe you will want to read [this part](https://learningpassion.wordpress.com/2016/06/21/git-tutorial-day-to-day-use-part-8-remote-branches/) of git tutorial.